# Combine Date and Time inputs in Streamlit with dataframe time column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I have a df that has a column `'Time'` in seconds:

```
Time
1
2
3
4
```

I want the user to input the date with a timestamp (eg format: `25/09/2022 12:30:00`). Then, I need to add a new column 'DateTime' which combines the user input datetime with my `'Time'` column. The `'DateTime'` column should look like this:

```
DateTime
25/09/2022 12:30:01
25/09/2022 12:30:02
25/09/2022 12:30:03
25/09/2022 12:30:04
```

I managed to do this in python, where the user input is on the terminal, however, I would like to have this in Streamlit. From the documentation, there is currently no possibility to input date with a timestamp in Streamlit, unless you enter them separately, as follows:

```py
start_date = st.date_input('Enter start date', value=datetime.datetime(2019,7,6))
start_time = st.time_input('Enter start time', datetime.time(8, 45))
```

So, this gives the user the possibility to enter the date and time separately, however I don't know how to derive my 'DateTime' column and add it to the df.
Appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.combine()` [function from pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html) to combine your `start_date` with `start_time`, after you have accomplished that. Make a new df named `DateTime` and loop through your `Time` df to concatenate the seconds to `DateTime`, after the concatenation, format the `DateTime`. You can then drop `Time` column after haven looped through it.

**Example:**

```py
# Your df that contains "Time" column
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time":[1, 2, 3, 4]})

start_date = st.date_input('Enter start date', value=datetime.datetime(2019,7,6))
start_time = st.time_input('Enter start time', datetime.time(8, 45))

start_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(start_date, start_time)

df["DateTime"] = [start_datetime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time) for time in df["Time"]]

df["DateTime"] = [date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") for date in df["DateTime"]]

df = df.drop(columns=["Time"])

st.dataframe(df)
```

Output:

```
              DateTime
0  06/07/2019 08:45:01
1  06/07/2019 08:45:02
2  06/07/2019 08:45:03
3  06/07/2019 08:45:04
```

Comment: Thanks Jamiu for the answer. It worked well!